# Building OpenCV as a static library leads to thousands of undefined references

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, static, ubuntu-18.04

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 and i want to build OpenCV(4.1.0) as static lib and create a sample program. Building OpenCV works flawlessly but i get thousands of errors when i run the test application.

### Building OpenCV:

- **configure cmake:**

  > cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D
  >   OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -D
  >   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D
  >   OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib-4.1.0/modules
  >   -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/opencv
  >   ..
- **build:**

  > make -j8
- **install:**

  > sudo make install
- **pkg-config setup:**

  > sudo cp unix-install/opencv4.pc /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/

### Sample Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  cv::Mat testmat;
  printf("Test\n");
  return 0;
}
```

- **build:**

  > g++ TestApp.cpp -o TestApp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`

  - **I get these errors:** [Full Console.log](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1562935328413.txt)

```
/usr/local/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(window_gtk.cpp.o): In function &#96;cvImageWidget_class_init(void*, void*)&amp;apos;: window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL24cvImageWidget_class_initPvS_+0xa): undefined reference to &#96;gtk_widget_get_type&amp;apos; window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL24cvImageWidget_class_initPvS_+0x15): undefined reference to &#96;g_type_class_peek&amp;apos; window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL24cvImageWidget_class_initPvS_+0x20): undefined reference to &#96;g_type_check_class_cast&amp;apos; /usr/local/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(window_gtk.cpp.o): In function &#96;icvOnTrackbar(_GtkWidget*, void*)&amp;apos;: window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL13icvOnTrackbarP10_GtkWidgetPv+0xd): undefined reference to &#96;gtk_range_get_type&amp;apos; window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL13icvOnTrackbarP10_GtkWidgetPv+0x18): undefined reference to &#96;g_type_check_instance_cast&amp;apos; window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL13icvOnTrackbarP10_GtkWidgetPv+0x20): undefined reference to &#96;gtk_range_get_value&amp;apos; /usr/local/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(window_gtk.cpp.o): In function &#96;std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace&amp;lt;CvWindow, std::allocator&amp;lt;CvWindow&amp;gt;, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2&amp;gt;::_M_dispose()&amp;apos;: window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZNSt23_Sp_counted_ptr_inplaceI8CvWindowSaIS0_ELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE10_M_disposeEv[_ZNSt23_Sp_counted_ptr_inplaceI8CvWindowSaIS0_ELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE10_M_disposeEv]+0x12): undefined reference to &#96;gtk_widget_destroy&amp;apos; /usr/local/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(window_gtk.cpp.o): In function &#96;icvWindowThreadLoop(void*)&amp;apos;: window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL19icvWindowThreadLoopPv+0x41): undefined reference to &#96;gtk_main_iteration_do&amp;apos; window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL19icvWindowThreadLoopPv+0x53): undefined reference to &#96;g_usleep&amp;apos; window_gtk.cpp:(.text._ZL19icvWindowThreadLoopPv+0x58): undefined reference to &#96;g_thread_yield&amp;apos; window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL19icvWindowThreadLoopPv+0x113): undefined reference to &#96;gtk_main_iteration_do&amp;apos; window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL19icvWindowThreadLoopPv+0x11d): undefined reference to &#96;g_usleep&amp;apos; window_gtk.cpp:(.text._ZL19icvWindowThreadLoopPv+0x122): undefined reference to &#96;g_thread_yield&amp;apos; /usr/local/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(window_gtk.cpp.o): In function &#96;cvImageWidget_size_request(_GtkWidget*, _GtkRequisition*)&amp;apos;: window_gtk.cpp:
(.text._ZL26cvImageWidget_size_requestP10_GtkWidgetP15_GtkRequisition+0x19): undefined reference to &#96;gtk_widget_get_type&amp;apos; window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL26cvImageWidget_size_requestP10_GtkWidgetP15_GtkRequisition+0x47): undefined reference to &#96;g_type_register_static_simple&amp;apos; window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL26cvImageWidget_size_requestP10_GtkWidgetP15_GtkRequisition+0x5b): undefined reference to &#96;g_type_check_instance_cast&amp;apos; /usr/local/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(window_gtk.cpp.o): In function &#96;cvImageWidget_set_size(_GtkWidget*, int, int)&amp;apos;: window_gtk.cpp:
.text._ZL22cvImageWidget_set_sizeP10_GtkWidgetii+0x19): undefined reference to &#96;gtk_widget_get_type&amp;apos; window_gtk.cpp:.text._ZL22cvImageWidget_set_sizeP10_GtkWidgetii+0x47): undefined reference to &#96;g_type_register_static_simple&amp;apos;
```

**I would be thankful for any help.**

### Testing a fix:

The obvious answer is that OpenCV can not generate a correct .pc file in static mod. **But i dont think thats the problem.** To verify i built OpenCV3.2.0(the .pc file generates correctly in 3.2.0 as far as i know) and installed the perbuilt version with "sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev". The prebuilt worked but i got the same errors with the self-built version. I diffchecked both files and they were pretty much the same.

**DiffCheck:** [diff](http://m.UploadEdit.com/bbtc/1562953559311.jpg)

**opencv.pc(pre-build):** [pre](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1562953932673.txt)

**opencv.pc(self-build):** [self](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/156295397895.txt)

**build-output(opencv):** [opencvbuild](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1562954865572.txt)

**build-output(testapp):** [testappbuild](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/156295491533.txt)

Comment: You may have good reasons for targeting 14.04, but it went out of support in April, and much of the software you might be trying to build with may have moved on.

Comment: Sorry I meant 18.04.

Comment: I kind of fixed it:   The first error when building with OpenCV3.2.0 is **undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'**. The -ljpeg library is linked under Libs.private in the .pc [file](http://m.UploadEdit.com/bbtc/1563169814915.jpg) and the command **pkg-config --libs opencv32** returns only the Libs without the Libs.private params. So copying the Libs.private params to the Libs params ["fixed"](http://m.UploadEdit.com/bbtc/1563170335821.jpg) the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I fixed it

My build command was missing the **--static** flag.

```
g++ TestApp.cpp -o TestApp `pkg-config --cflags --static --libs opencv4`
```

Now it can build my test application with OpenCV3.2.0 with no problems but I get this error when i use OpenCV4.1.0.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgflags_shared
```

I dont think I need this lib so i fixed this by removing **-lgflags_shared** from the opencv.pc file. Doing it manually works but using the command line is more convenient.

```
sed -i 's/-lgflags_shared //g' unix-install/opencv4.pc
```